# Accessing CRS info with pyqgis in a standalone application

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-2

I'm currently having trouble accessing and defining CRS information in a standalone application. I've read the API documentation and have tried it in the python console in QGIS 2.2.0. The python console works fine. I'm able to get the information I need. But the layers in my stand alone application do not have have valid CRS's. What is the reason for this?

Code:

```
import qgis
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import *
from qgis.gui import *

import pdb

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath( r"C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis", True )
QgsApplication.initQgis()
app = QgsApplication([], True)  

print "Testing Json crs:"
layer = QgsVectorLayer("E:/GIS_Data/GeoJsonRendering_Test/test.json" ,  'musym', "ogr")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
print layer.isValid()
print layer.crs().isValid()
print layer.crs().authid()

print "Testing QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem:"

t = QgsCoordinateTransform()
projSrc = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(3857, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.EpsgCrsId)
projDest = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.EpsgCrsId)

print projSrc.isValid()
print projDest.isValid()

print "Testing memory layer CRS:"
vTemp = QgsVectorLayer("Point?crs=EPSG:3857", "temporary_points", "memory")
print vTemp.isValid()
print vTemp.crs().isValid()
```

Output:

```
Testing Json crs:
True
False

Testing QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem:
False
False
Testing memory layer CRS:
True
False
```

So I have two valid layers without valid projections.

Here is the output for that code in the python console in QGIS:

```
Testing Json crs:
True
True
EPSG:3857
Testing QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem:
True
True
Testing memory layer CRS:
True
True
```

So my code only works in the QGIS python console. I'm assuming that I am not defining settings that need to be defined, but I"m not quite sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Could you provide us with your sample json file?

Comment: I would like to, but I'm not currently working on that problem. So I don't know if I could currently replicate the exact bug.

Answer (score 3):

I experienced the same problem, and I have finally solved it by changing the order of the first three lines.

Try with this:

```
QgsApplication.initQgis()
app = QgsApplication([], True)
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath( r"C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis", True )
...
```